# How to use FuncAnimation to animate a sequence of points/tuples in a grid

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am doing a path-finding algorithm implementation in python, I have a grid and the obtained path. So I wanna use FuncAnimation to animate the sequence of points from the start to the goal in the grid. I try to code this but it doesn't give me the line. This is what I did, In this example code I give the grid and the path(positions x,y in the grid), but the output is just the grid without the path, I don't know what to do to fix the problem, please help!

```
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def mazeanimation(grid, route):

        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))

        ax.imshow(grid, cmap=plt.cm.terrain)

        line, = ax.plot([],[], color="black")

        def init():
            line.set_data([],[])
            return line,

        def animate(i):
            x = route[i][0]

            y = route[i][1]

            line.set_data(x, y)
            return line,

        FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, blit=True) 


grid = np.array([

        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

route = [(13, 1), (12, 2), (11, 3), (10, 4), (9, 5), (8, 5),
         (7, 5), (6, 5), (5, 5), (4, 5), (3, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), 
         (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (2, 13), 
         (2, 14), (3, 15)]

mazeanimation(grid, route)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by making use of `matplotlib`'s interactive mode:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#inputs###
grid = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])

route = [(13, 1), (12, 2), (11, 3), (10, 4), (9, 5), (8, 5),
         (7, 5), (6, 5), (5, 5), (4, 5), (3, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), 
         (2, 8), (2, 9), (2, 10), (2, 11), (2, 12), (2, 13), 
         (2, 14), (3, 15)]
#setup the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
ax.imshow(grid, cmap=plt.cm.terrain)
line, = ax.plot([],[], color="black")

##### set interactive mode####
plt.ion()   
plt.show()


for i,j in route:
#set up the canvas
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
    line, = ax.plot(i,j,'.',c='black')
    plt.pause(0.1)
```

## Here's how the route looks:

[image: route]

## Alternately, with [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/animation_api.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [], []
ln, = plt.plot([], [], '.',c='black')

def init():
    ax.imshow(grid, cmap=plt.cm.terrain)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    xdata.append(frame[0])
    ydata.append(frame[1])
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=route,init_func=init, blit=True)
plt.show()
```